# Progress 4GL - is CRC value of table fixed for repeated loading .df?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I'm facing CRC error occurs with existing r-code after loading a .df file without adding the POSITION of the field in it.

**Step 1:**

I have loaded the .df file with adding POSITON of the field for the first time and compiled my .p program..The program was working fine without any issues

CRC value for table(4692) and .r (4692) matched.

**Step 2:**

I have loaded the same .df file but this time without adding the POSTION of the field in it.
I found CRC value for table(64665) and .r(4692) mismatched. so that I am getting CRC error.

Now my question here is that..is this CRC error will be fixed if I load the same .df(Step 1)?
If yes then after loading CRC value for table and .r will be matched? so that I dont need recompilation

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if the df is the same, then the CRC will match.
There are certain changes that have no effect on CRC but that's not your question. :)

Comment: Please enlighten me what are certain changes that have no effect on CRC

Comment: see https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/20245 for changes that affect CRC

Comment: CRC calculations and related issues can also be sensitive to the version of Progress that you are using.