# Progress 4GL - What are certain changes that have no effect/effect on CRC?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I am new to progress 4GL and I would like to what are certain changes that have effect/no effect on CRC?

What happens when I load newly xxbd_det.df file for the first time in db and compile .p?
What happens when I delete the same xxbd_det.df file and reload it again in same db? CRC value in already existing .r will be matched with table xx ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Progress 4GL - is CRC value of table fixed for repeated loading .df?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69925322/progress-4gl-is-crc-value-of-table-fixed-for-repeated-loading-df)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a complex topic with OpenEdge version dependent subtleties so I will stay very high level.

0. There is not a single CRC relating r-code to the db anymore. That, thankfully, stopped being the case 30 or so years ago.
1. Adding tables, fields, and indexes does not invalidate existing r-code in any modern release. Existing r-code will not be able to use new objects but they also don't break anything.
2. Having said that, dynamically coded queries ***can*** reference new objects. Because they are dynamic the compiler doesn't get to enforce anything about matching CRCs.
3. If you remove an object (delete a table, field or index) r-code that references that object will fail. You must re-compile such r-code. In the case of indexes a different index will be chosen by the compiler. Deleted tables and fields will require you to modify the code.
4. Changing certain attributes doesn't break anything (for example changing a field's FORMAT).
5. Renaming things will break your code.
6. Replacing a deleted object with a new object that has the same name and makeup (the second part of your question) will probably not require a recompile but I wouldn't want to make a habit of it.